# Get XML node value into a variable as separate xml

Tags: xml, powershell

Would like to know, how to get content of an XML node as a full XML document in powershell. The structure is following:

```
<root>
    <apphdr></apphdr>
    <document></document>
</root>
```

I need all the contents for 'document' tags including the tags. Can`t wrap my mind around it on how to get it as separate xml instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) is an easy way:

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<root>
    <apphdr></apphdr>
    <document></document>
</root>
"@
$document = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//root/document')
$document.OuterXml
```

Or to retrieve all document nodes:

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<root>
    <apphdr></apphdr>
    <document>doc1</document>
    <document>doc2</document>
</root>
"@
$documents = $xml.SelectNodes('//root/document')
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's create a sample [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.7.2) (alias `xml`):

```sh
$xml = [xml] @'
<root>
    <apphdr></apphdr>
    <document><child/></document>
</root>
'@
```

Create a new `XmlDocument`, [import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_XmlDocument_ImportNode_System_Xml_XmlNode_System_Boolean_) the `document` node and [append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild?view=netframework-4.7.2) it as the first child (the document element).

```sh
$newXml = [xml]::new()
$newNode = $newXml.ImportNode( $xml.root.document, $true )
$newXml.AppendChild( $newNode )
$newXml.Save("$PWD\NewDocument.xml")
```

Note that the `AppendChild` call is important, because after `ImportNode`, the element is not yet associated with a location within the new document.